# Javascript if else statement to hide and show div

Tags: javascript

Please refer to the following codes :

```
<div id="message-1" onclick="javascript:showresponddiv(this.id)>
</div>
<div id="respond-1" style="display:none;">
</div>
<div id="message-2" onclick="javascript:showresponddiv(this.id)>
</div>
<div id="respond-2" style="display:none;">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showresponddiv(messagedivid){
    var responddivid = messagedivid.replace("message-", "respond-");
    if (document.getElementById(responddivid).style.display=="none"){
        document.getElementById(responddivid).style.display="inline";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(responddivid).style.display="none";
    }
}
</script>
```

The codes above already success make the respond div appear when user click on message div. The respond div will disappear when user click on message div again. Now my question is how to make the respond div of 1st message disappear when user click on 2nd message to display the respond div of 2nd message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should give the "respond" divs a common class:

```
<div id="respond-1" class="response' style="display:none;"></div>
```

Then you can get all divs by using `getElementsByTagName`, compare the class and hide them on a match:

```
function hideAllResponses() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(var i = divs.length; i-- ;) {
        var div = divs[i];
        if(div.className === 'response') {
            div.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

We cannot use `getElementsByClassName`, because this method is [not supported by IE8 and below](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11). But of course this method can be extended to make use of it if it is supported (same for [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll)). This is left as an exercise for the reader.

---

**Further notes:**

- Adding `javascript:` to the click handler is syntactically not wrong but totally unnecessary. Just do:

  ```
  onclick="showresponddiv(this.id)"
  ```
- If you have to do a lot of DOM manipulation of this kind, you should have a look at a library such as [*jQuery*](http://jquery.com/) which greatly simplify such tasks.

---

**Update:** If always only **one response** is shown and you are worried about speed, then store a reference to opened one:

```
var current = null;

function showresponddiv(messagedivid){
    var id = messagedivid.replace("message-", "respond-"),
        div = document.getElementById(id);

    // hide previous one
    if(current && current !== div) {
        current.style.display =  'none';
    }   

    if (div.style.display=="none"){
        div.style.display="inline";
        current = div;
    } 
    else {
        div.style.display="none";
    }
}
```

*Edit: Fixed logic. See a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/TpF24/)*.

Comment: @Felix Kling, you are very information! Your codes work perfect for me. Thank you very much. If my page has 200 divs, then the loading speed for hide the div should be very long since it need to loop through 200 divs... I wondering if there is code to detect the previous selected div?

Comment: Wow, thank you, but your code else {div.style.display="none";} is not working. So, when user click 2 times on the same message div, it will not hide back the respond div. I really don't know what is going on since your if else statement is seem correct.

Comment: @zac1987: Slight error in my logic. For the second click, `current === div` so it will be hidden first by `if(current)` and then shown again because the next `if` clause is `true`. Please the updated code, I also added a demo.

Comment: @Felix Kling, thanks again your perfect guidance and codes. It works perfectly now. I try to understand the !== there, if the the data type of variable current is not the same as div, then it won't execute the 1st if statement, so it won't execute the 2nd if statement to display the respond of div. Okay, I understood your codes now. Thank you. You are GENIUS! Thanks Thanks!

Comment: @zac1987: You're welcome :) You could also accept this answer then ;) And `!==` does not only compare the data type but also the value. Using strict equality is encouraged (to prevent unwanted tupe conversion which is, granted, not likely in this case, but it is more consistent).

Comment: What is mean by !== actually? I think it mean the value is same but data type is not same? or it mean the value is not same but data type is same? or it mean the value and data type both are not same? LOL. I tried to vote your answer but it gave error "u need 15 reputation". May I know where is the button to click to accept ur answer?

Comment: @zac1987: See the two links I posted in the comment to your question. I see, `!==` can be tricky to understand :D. `===` means that both, the data type and the value must be the same. `!==` means that the value must be different, but the data type must be the same. E.g. `0 != false` yields `false` because `false` is treated as `0`, but `0 !== false` yields `true` because `0` is a number and `false` a boolean.

Comment: @zac1987: You should also accept answer to your previous questions if they helped you.

Comment: @Felix Kling, I see!! Now I understood it already. Thank you. You are a very helpful person!! Thank you. God will bless u more :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add some class to all divs with id="respond-"

e.g

```
<div id="respond-1" class="classname" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="respond-2" class="classname" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Now at first row of your function "showresponddiv()" you should find all divs with class "classname" and hide them.

With [jQuery](http://jquery.com) it is simple code:

```
$(".classname").hide();
```

jQuery - is a Javascript Library that helps you to easy manipulate with DOM and provides cross-browser compatibility.

Also you can look to [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) - it is a JavaScript CSS selector engine used by jQuery for selecting DOM elements

Comment: The OP might not know what jQuery is. You should explain it and link to it.

Comment: Actually I know jQuery. Does jquery $(".classname").hide(); support IE8 or below? If so, I should use it, because it doesn't need to loop through all divs...

Comment: @zac1987: jQuey works in every browser, but of course it still has to loop over the elements (it can only use the methods that are available in the browser) albeit in a highly optimized way. Only because you cannot see it does not mean that jQuery does not use a loop ;)