# Hiding a Div using php

Tags: php, css, caching, html, hide

I am currently hiding a div based on an if statement. The method I use is, use `echo` out a `css` style of `display: none`

Here is what I am doing specifically:

```
<style>
  #content{
    <?php
      if(condition){
          echo 'display:none';
      }
    ?>
  }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="content">
       Foo bar
    </div>
</body>
```

My question being, Is this a good method for a hiding a div? Is it possible that browser cache the style and therefore ignore the `echo`-ed out `css` style?

Comment: you could just not include the div at all. but i'm not suer what you mean about the style being cached.

Comment: Inline styles are cached with the page - not alone. If it's good or not that depends, your question does not contain enough information to properly judge about the level of good I'd say.

Comment: ...or you could only give the div a class name which applies `display: none` when you want to hide it. Or even an inline style.

Comment: @Dagon well you know how browser store bit and pieces of html like images style etc to load page faster if a user visits back again.

Comment: Here is a good question on dynamically generated css with pros and cons http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853063/why-arent-php-files-used-for-custom-css-and-js

Comment: @VidhuShresthBhatnagar - Browsers cache the images etc, but I've never known a browser to cache the HTML in the way you seem to think it might. Dagons initial comment is the usual method, and it's also cleaner when viewing the code, and also quicker if there might be a lot of content in that div.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using Php in your CSS (Cascade Style Sheet) is not "proper",

Also, You can use Php in your HTML:

```
<body>
    <?php if (condition){ ?>
        <div id="content">
           Foo bar
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
```

With this code, div block don't appear, (and you don't use it with JavaScript), You can use this for just hidden your div :

```
 <body>
    <div id="content" <?php if (condition){ echo 'style="display:none;"'; } ?>>
       Foo bar
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I like the first solution also, but I dont' know how to implement it...what would be the complete code I can paste in there in a .php file to see it in action? It's the (condition) part I have a problem with

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a class:

```
<style>
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

And than apply it with PHP:

```html
<div id="content" <?php print ( condition ? 'class="hidden"' : '' ); ?> >
```

Comment: How else would you hide it other than using an inline style? And I also think that this is not a "semantic" class. I assumed that the OP wanted the div to be hidden and not to be taken off the page, 'cause of using `display:none` in the question already. :)

Answer (score 1):

That would not be the best way to hide a div. Since PHP is parsed server-side, you might as well have the if statement include or exclude the div instead of echoing a CSS class. The only time that would be useful with a CSS class is if you plan to use JavaScript to show the div on the page later on, while the user is on the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
<div runat="server" id="theDiv"> 

Code behind is
{
theDiv.Visible = False;
}
```

or

Most people would use javascript

Heres a previous thread that will help you out:

[Javascript if else statement to hide and show div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484560/javascript-if-else-statement-to-hide-and-show-div)

Comment: just so u know im using php not asp.net :P

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the standard way of hiding a div. With regard to the browser cache, it shouldn't cache this as it isn't in an external stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

I generally try to avoid using PHP Conditionals inside of CSS; especially inline CSS (CSS that is on the same page).

I would keep your CSS in its own CSS file and use the PHP conditional to either add a "hide" class to the DIV -OR- not echo the DIV at all.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<body>
    <div id="content" <?php if(conditional) : ?>class="hide"<?php endif;?>>
       Foo bar
    </div>
</body>
```

or alternatively

```
<?php $class = (conditional) ? "hide" : ""; ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<body>

    <div id="content" class="<?=$class?>">
       Foo bar
    </div>
</body>
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<body>

    <?php if (conditional) : ?>
    <div id="content">
       Foo bar
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</body>
```

Many times the div needs to be outputted so it can be re-displayed using JavaScript (e.g. carousels, sliders, etc.)