# How do I hide the div if the Var is empty?

Tags: php, html, css, hide, var

I am trying to hide an entire piece of CSS, a field, when the result of the vr is empty. How should I get this done? I currently managed to make sure that when the data is empty in the database, it doesn't display anything at all, otherwise it does.

```
<div class="row row_border">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3"><div class="icon"><span class="icon-tree101"></span></div></div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-9">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"><h4>Buitenruimte</h4></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 list_name">
                <?php if (empty(Vars::$content->object->data['obw_tuintype'])) { echo "";   } else { echo (Vars::$content->object->data['obw_tuintype']); } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                             
</div>
```

that's the code I have so far, thanks.

Comment: You have not actually asked a specific question.  "How do I get this done?" is far too broad.  It is unclear what the problem with your code is, and it is unclear what precisely that code is failing to provide to reach your goal.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855535/hiding-a-div-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not put the `if` statement outside of the `div`? That way, if the element is empty, the entire `div` won't be displayed at all:

```
<?php if(!empty(Vars::$content->object->data['obw_tuintype'])){ ?>
    <div class="row row_border">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3"><div class="icon"><span class="icon-tree101"></span></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"><h4>Buitenruimte</h4></div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 list_name">
                    <?php echo (Vars::$content->object->data['obw_tuintype']); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                             
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```